# what is Embedded XAP mean in WP7 ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

I have created a application for Silverlight Windows Phone 7. On uploading the xap for beta testing in the WP7 Marketplace, the App submission was failed and resulted in error message as below:

> 1019: We don’t allow embedded XAPs. Remove the Bin\Debug\ONCALL.xap
>   embedded XAPs and then try again.

Can anyone please let me know What could be the problem.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your *.xap* file to *.zip* file, open it in Explorer and check is there any other xap files in it.

Looks like, you have attached the debug version of ONCALL app. I don't know is it your application name, or this is a subpoject.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your response. I verified the XAP file as well. Also I try uploading the xap from release version. Still I get the same error. I couldnt upload my application.

Comment: Is your app name  ONCALL? or it's a name of your app part?